# Get child name from Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

If I have something like:

```
child name: "value"
```

How can I get the childname? I know its possible to get the value, but what about the other?

Comment: It's called the key. Does that help?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The child name in this situation is the "KEY" of that value. So use the reference object and call getKey() on it.

```
String name = ref.getKey();
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("root/childName");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
     var key = snapshot.key; // "childName";
});
```

**[UPDATED]**

Sorry I posted for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

get all child:

```
    dbRef.child("tipo_arte").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            item.clear();
            item.add("");

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                item.add(child.getKey());   //Pega o nome de cada tipo de arte

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```